# Finding the area between curves, calculus, how does my answer look?

Tags: calculus

i got a test tomorrow and before i step in I wanna make sure i understand this.

[image: Image of question]

How does my answer look? The prof didnt provide any solutions, just the worksheets, so im worried everything im doing is wrong.

Comment: The integral computation is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me. Seems like you will do fine on the test!

Comment: It's good, except that you omitted the limits of evaluation $|^8_2$ for a couple of steps

Comment: Perfect integration. Just don't forget to put the limit of integration

Answer (score 0):

The limits of integration seems strange, and more other - too.
For $x\in[0,2]\quad \dfrac1{\sqrt{2x}}\ge 0,$
so it should be
$$\int_0^2\frac1{\sqrt{2x}}\,dx = \sqrt2\int_0^2\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{x}\biggr|_0^2 = 2.$$
But results are the same.